# When I am trying to compile a file.java by "javac" command, it gives me "file not found" error, though I have done the path and variable of JDK

Tags: java, windows, cmd, javac

This is exactly what appears:

```
C:\Users\Ammar\Desktop>javac Saad.java

error: file not found: Saad.java

Usage: javac <options> <source files>

use --help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: What is the full path to the file Saad.java? Is it `C:\Users\Ammar\Desktop\Saad.java`?

Comment: So if you type `dir Saad.java`, does it show the file? If not, then why are you surprised by the error, when the file isn't *there*?

Comment: yes, this is the full path of the file, and when I did that  gave me file not found.

Comment: Also, the extension of the file is.java, not txt

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure you are in the same path where you stored your file Saad.java (You can use dir command to check if the file exist in your current path).

2- Check capitalization (Write it exactly as it saved).

Comment: #2 doesn't apply (since this is Windows).

Comment: I made all this and still have the same problem.

Comment: What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

I did it, Yahooooooooooooooooooo!!!!!!!!!

The problem was that I linked my pc to my One Drive account, and One drive makes synchronization with my Desktop and changed its path to (C:\Users\Ammar\One drive\Desktop.
As soon as I stopped the synchronization the path returned normally and I found my file and compiled it.
Thanks for my efforts!!!!!! Hahaahhaaa
Hope it helps anyone.